# RobotFramework : Scroll into view issue

Tags: selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

I regularly have the `following error`

> " couldn't scroll into view"

I know KW in `ExtendedSelenium2libray` but it's it is not compatible with the latest version of selenium2library`

Other solution is to use

```
Execute javascript | document.getElementById('myId')[0].scrollIntoView()
```

But how use that for HTML < select > < option > value or index ? Maybe there is a solution with a keyword? Thx a lot guys

Comment: Have you tried [Set Focus To Element](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Set%20Focus%20To%20Element)?

Comment: Yes not better with that :(